# How to Write a Number in A Text File Faster?

Tags: python, file-io, filesystems, fwrite

I have written a program that take 0.1092 seconds to generate a number but 787.26012 seconds =13 minute  to write that number (3.81 MB) in/on a text file.

```
import time
import sys
import math
start = time.time()

input_file="First1_58MB_enwik9.txt"
with open(input_file, "rb") as file: #--> open file in binary read mode
  byte_obj = file.read() #--> read all binary data
g=int.from_bytes( byte_obj, byteorder=sys.byteorder)
binary_dt=bin(g)


int_v=int(binary_dt,2)
length = math.ceil(math.log(int_v, 256))
res = int.to_bytes(int_v, length=length, byteorder='little', signed=False)

open("output_file_2.txt", "wb").write(res)

end = time.time()
print("Total time (in seconds) = ",(end - start))
#---------------------------
start = time.time()
with open("output_file_1.txt", 'w') as f:
  f.write('%d' % g)

end = time.time()
print("Total time (in seconds) = ",(end - start))
```

Is there a faster way to write that large number on a  text file?

Also, if I write the number in another type of file will it be faster, say if I write the number a binary file or a file without extension?

**PS:** What is the term for file that has no extension?

Comment: Writing the number in binary would amount to making (a quick) copy of original file. What's taking most of the time in your code is probably the conversion of the input file's "binary" contents to the ASCII character sequence representing the equivalent decimal number. What's the purpose of what you're doing — this might be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: BTW, files without an extension don't have a special name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to generate 30mb file within a second when I used the code below.

```
s = "hey"*10000000 # multiply "hey" 10000000 times and then return the string
with open("output_file_1.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Is it necessary to explicity tell python that the object we are writing to .txt file is integer? If no, then...

> Consider `g` as string instead of number and change your code to
>   `f.write(g)`. And then check if you see time improvement.

Comment: No it is not important if we can get back that integer from the string/text file/or any other format, could you edit my code and add a part from where we get that integer back? Thanks.

Comment: just open and read. `s = open("output_file_1.txt", "rb").read()
`